# Every time i run Vmware i get this error; Error While powering on: The VMware Authorization Service is not running

Tags: windows-7, vmware-workstation

Error While powering on: The VMware Authorization Service is not running.

To fix this error i go to:

"Start / Control Panel / Administrative Tools / Services, clicked on VMware Authorization Service in the list & click the Start link on the left."

but i have to do this every time i want to use the Vitual Machine .

Does anyone know a permanent solution?

i've also tried double clicking it and changing startUp type = "Automatic".
But that did'nt work

Answer (score 0):

I just started having the same issue on my Windows 7 system.  I had to manually start the service even though it is configured as automatic start.

Comment: Please don't leave answers stating that you have the same problem as the one described in the question. If you have sufficient reputation, [you may upvote](https://superuser.com/privileges/vote-up) the question. Alternatively, "star" it as a favorite and you will be notified of any new answers.